# Преобразование данных из таблицы в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста со следующей проблемой.

Данные из таблицы отображаются в Python в виде списка списков:

```
[
    ['S1', 'G1', 'T1', 'N', 'TN1'],
    ['S1', 'G1', 'T1', 'P', 'TP1'],
    ['S1', 'G2', 'T2', 'N', 'TN2'],
    ['S1', 'G2', 'T2', 'P', 'TP2'],
    ['S2', 'G3', 'T3', 'N', 'TN3'],
    ['S2', 'G3', 'T3', 'P', 'TP3']
]
```

Мне нужно, преобразовать список список в словарь такого типа:

```
{
    'S1': {
        'G1': {
            'T': 'T1',
            'P': 'TP1',
            'N': 'TN1'
        },
        'G2': {
            'T': 'T2',
            'P': 'TP2',
            'N': 'TN2'
        },
    },
    'S2': {
        'G3': {
            'T': 'T3',
            'P': 'TP3',
            'N': 'TN3'
        }
    }
}
```

Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: не очень понятна логика с `T`

Comment: глубина вложенности словарей может изменяться?

Comment: откуда берутся ключи `T`, `P`, `N`?

Comment: глубина вложенности словарей не измениться. Ключи T, P, N - это обязательные ключи (они будут всегда) P, N беруться из списка T относиться к T1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [
    ['S1', 'G1', 'T1', 'N', 'TN1'],
    ['S1', 'G1', 'T1', 'P', 'TP1'],
    ['S1', 'G2', 'T2', 'N', 'TN2'],
    ['S1', 'G2', 'T2', 'P', 'TP2'],
    ['S2', 'G3', 'T3', 'N', 'TN3'],
    ['S2', 'G3', 'T3', 'P', 'TP3']
]

res = dict()

for obj in data:
    if obj[0] not in res:
        res[obj[0]] = dict()

    if obj[1] not in res[obj[0]]:
        res[obj[0]][obj[1]] = dict()

    res[obj[0]][obj[1]]['T'] = obj[4]
    res[obj[0]][obj[1]][obj[3]] = obj[4]

print(res)
```

Но c T непонятно как быть, например если будут такие данные:

```
['S1', 'G1', 'T1', 'N', 'TN1'],
['S1', 'G1', 'T2', 'N', 'TN2'],
```

Comment: Оргомное спасибо. С Т не правильно объяснил но испраление вашего кода минимальны 
res[obj[0]][obj[1]]['T'] = obj[2]

Comment: В Т1 гарантируется одинаковый ответ, Т1,Т2 (как вы показали) не будет)